# How to find x, y of center of ROI in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have segmented my mass in mammogram. Now I want to find the `x` and `y` of its center.
I tried `regionprops(image,'centroid')` function but it seems that it does not give me the true position.
could anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Please provide images and small self contained code

Comment: Have a look at the property `WeightedCentroid` of `regionprops`.

Answer (score 1):

The `'Centroid'` property computed by `regionprops` returns the *center of mass* of the region, that is, it is the average `x`, `y` locations of the *highlighted* pixels only.
If you want the center of the bounding box enclosing the segment, you can manipulate the `'BoundingBox'` property:

```
st = regionprops( image, 'BoundingBox' );
bb = vertcat( st.BoundingBox ); %// all BBs as a single n-by-4
cntr = bb(1:2) + 0.5*bb(3:4); %// coordinates of the centers
```

You can visualize the results using

```
figure('Name','Showing BB centers');
imshow( image, [] ); hold on;
scatter( cntr(:,1), cntr(:,2), 200, '+y' );
```